# How to fill Grid in C# with user controls dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a simple question and yet don't know how to search about it! i searched for hours with no luck!

I'm making a WPF application, the application has a grid in one of its windows, I want to fill this grid with a User Control dynamically , that is when the input is 5

**for example,** 
I want my grid to have 5 × 5 user controls in that grid.

Comment: is this grid taking the full window? is the input coming from another window? Is the Window already created or are you creating it at the time you give your input? You need to be a little clearer in what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: ok I didn't know that was necessary. Any way

I have Window, the window has its content as user control, first we take the input and the content of the window is switched to another user control , of course the input is passed

the new user control has a Grid int which i want to fill , this grid is part of the user control, and not filling it

Comment: are you using mvvm or codebehind

Comment: I guess both, I don't really care how I do it, any method is good for me.

but I think I prefer code in this one

Comment: You need an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution I can think of is to use `ItemsControl`, specify `ItemsPanel` as `UniformGrid` and bind its size:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Path=Size}" Columns="{Binding Path=Size}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

where you view model would look like, more or less, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public List<MyItemClass> MyItems{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. +1